# VLOOKUP Excel general references

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I have a `VLOOKUP` table in SHEET2 where the values in the body of the table are as a result of some complicated formulas taking data from SHEET1. I have set up the table with the formulas associated with row9 of SHEET1:
The formula throughout the table is basically:
`=IF(((SHEET1!B9)*B2)<7,7,((SHEET1!B5)*B2))`

The formulas are identical for row 12, row 15, row 18 etc... with only the change of B9 to B12, or B15 etc...
I am inserting `=VLOOKUP(B8,SHEET2!$A$1:$G$27,2,FALSE)` into B9 of SHEET1.
Hence, I would like the `VLOOKUP` for B12, B15, .... to lookup the value from the same table however, the formulas within the table need to adapt to the correct row and I don't know how to do this?

HELP please!

Comment: Show an example of your Data and ho the result should be

Comment: I can't do this unfortunately. I suppose what I am essentially looking for is a way to enter a general term into the formula instead of 'B9'. This term can be any multiple of 3 in the column B

Comment: You have to write how the result is and which formula to update an example will explain

Comment: @Emily, your question is not clear.  Are you saying that formulas in adjacent rows need to reference cells that are 3 rows apart?

Comment: The formula is =IF(((SHEET1!B9)*B2)<7,7,((SHEET1!B5)*B2)) when doing a VLOOKUP in row 9,

Comment: When doing a VLOOKUP in row 12, 15 etc.... The formula should change to =IF(((SHEET1!B12)*B2)<7,7,((SHEET1!B5)*B2))
or =IF(((SHEET1!B15)*B2)<7,7,((SHEET1!B5)*B2)) etc

Comment: @Bandersnatch Apologies, I am saying the whole look up table is referenced to row 9. I would like to do a VLOOKUP using the same table but for row 9+3n and therefore the formulas within the table need to automatically update

Comment: Still not clear, but ROW() gives the row number of the current row.  Will that help?  I'm also wondering if you may have circular references. Sheet1!B9 refers to an array on Sheet 2 which includes cells that refer to Sheet1!B9.

Comment: So ="B"&ROW() typed in row 12 will evaluate to B12.

Comment: @Bandersnatch thank you that may will be what i want